# Will my US immigration time duration effects, if my parents come back to pakistan

Tags: usa, immigration

My parents have been living in US since 2 years  and they are green card holder, but not have citizenship now. I have applied for US immigration on base of my father who is currently doing job there and Its been a 5 months ago that I applied and my process submission has been successfully approved. Now my parents want to come back to Pakistan and stay here for 1 years so I want to know following.

Does my process time (which takes around 5 to 6 years as I read on us immigration site for unmarried person and more than 21 years ) will effect if they stay Pakistan for 1 year or more than this? Does this time will deduct for whole process time duration?
Does Citizenship time which my parents get from US will effect if they stay Pakistan for 1 year or more than this?

Comment: The [hoary details](http://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/ilink/docView/SLB/HTML/SLB/0-0-0-1/0-0-0-11261/0-0-0-30960/0-0-0-31016.html#0-0-0-19579).

Answer (score 3):

If your parents go back to Pakistan for 1 year, they should probably apply for a re-entry permit from the US government before leaving. Such a long absence, without a permit, can be seen as abandoning the permanent residency status and they may end up losing their green card.

Once they get back to the US, if their green card is still valid, the clock for citizenship will be reset. They'll need to wait for 5 years *after they're back* before being eligible for citizenship. That's assuming they won't have any more significant (>6 months) absences from the US.

Your process will continue as long as their own green card is valid. If they become citizens, your process will continue as long as they reside in the US.

They cannot sponsor your immigration to the US if they themselves don't stay there. The sponsorship is for you to live close to them, so if they don't live in the US - you have no reason to be there either.

Comment: Thanks @littleadv for your answer, i still have few queries regarding your answer.
Is maximum time 6 months, to stay outside of US without permission(for green card holder)? I mean they can come to pakistan for 5 months without any permission and this 5 months will not effects of duration of my process and their Citizenship?
How and where to get Permission for leaving US for at least 1 year?

Comment: @Aleem Those are slightly different questions and you might want to separate them into a different thread.